# How to abort a notebook in DataFactory

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to write a query to a table in data factory.
I already have functions and query and it works fine.
Now I want to abort the notebook as soon as the code enters the except part.
I have this right now:

```py
try:
    df = spark.sql(query)
    df.write.format(formato).mode(method).saveAsTable(table)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "An error occured while writing the query to the table: {}".format(e)
        dbutils.notebook.exit(msg)
```

It does actually show a message on the notebook and stop it from continuing. BUT, on data factory it does show that the run was successfully [image: succeeded], but I wanted to show as "Failed" [image: failed].

Does anyone can help me?

Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same with your code and my Notebook is also gave me Success.

[image]

Here, you are handling the error and passing a message to the notebook using `dbutils.notebook.exit(msg)`.

Notebook won't fail when it exited with a message but the databricks notebook execution will be aborted.

If you want to get the **reason(Message)** causing the abort of the databricks notebook in the ADF pipeline, use the below expression after the **Success of the notebook activity**.

```
@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput
```

(OR)

If you want **Notebook activity to fail, you need to generate the error** and abort the notebook like below sample.

```
try:
    df = spark.sql(query)
    df.write.format(formato).mode(method).saveAsTable(table)
except Exception as e:
    msg = "An error occured while writing the query to the table: {}".format(e)
    logging.error(msg)
    raise
```

Now, to get the error message in ADF, use the below expression after the **Failure of the Notebook activity**.

```
@activity('Notebook1').output.runError
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @rakesh, but I am not understanding where I should put the @activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput or the @activity('Notebook1').output.runError. Can you please provide a little bit more context? I am quite new to all of this! Thanks :)

Comment: Here, I have stored error message in a string variable named `message` by using set variable activity like below. https://i.imgur.com/tysrkGv.png. Give the expression as shown in this picture

Comment: `@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput`- this one you need to use when you want the notebook activity succeeded. Use it like below https://i.imgur.com/wXrOA1z.png

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @rakesh!! It's now working :D
I just have one more question, I am sorry, but the example that was here was a notebook, when you have a "execute pipeline" square, how would you do it?

Comment: As your primary ask is answered, could you please raise another question on this ask with proper details so that I can understand better about your requirement and answer it if that's to my knowledge.

Comment: You are absolutely right!! I am so sorry! And thank you so much for the help :D Meanwhile I just opened a new question :)